# Getting Error using selenium with powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium

I am using Selenium with PowerShell as

```
$driver = start-sechrome
Enter-SeUrl https://www.google.com -Driver $Driver
```

But i am getting popup as 'failed to load extension . Loading of unpacked drivers is disabled by admin'

Please suggest how can this be fixed using PowerShell, as i have searched google and can only find solutions for c# and java.

Comment: Try `$driver = Start-SeChrome -DisableAutomationExtension`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Nops, still same popup

Comment: any help on this?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen any further help?